# ¿EL ERROR "No se esperaba /BIOCaptureFinger en este momento." A QUE SE DEBE?

Tags: java-ee, oracle-11g, weblogic

Estoy utilizando el servidor WebLogic en JavaEE, especificamente WebLogic 11gR1, puedo levantar la pagina de administracion de WebLogic "localhost:7001/console", pero cuando apago y prendo el pc no puedo acceder al dominio que habia creado, me aparece el siguiente error:

> No se esperaba /BIOCaptureFinger en este momento.

Ese error ma aparece en la consola (CMD) de windows cuando intento correr el archivo "startWebLogic.cmd" que esta en kla carpeta del dominio, cuando estaba recien creado el dominio si funcionaba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pude resolver el inconveniente, soy un usuario principalmente de Linux, pero estoy trabajando en Windows, asi que acudi a una persona que trabaja normalmente en esos entornos y pudimos conseguir el error, se trata de que en mi variable de entorno "classpath" estaba el valor "/BIOCaptureFinger". Yo en ningun momento agregue eso de forma manual, supongo que lo hizo algun programa, nose porque aparecio eso alli, el hecho es que quitando ese valor de alli, ya luego el servidor corrio sin problemas.